# Android ListView Adapter multiple Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I did one List Adapter - it works but I want to do some Listview on different Activities and here is the question if I need to do a new Adapter for each Activity?
Is there a way to make one ListAdapter depend on which Activity is selected to display a specific view?

I was looking for something about getView but I can not use it.

This is my Adapter in first Activity:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ContextObj;
    List<FruitNames> TempList;


    public ListViewAdapter(List<FruitNames> listValue, Context context)
    {
        this.ContextObj = context;

        this.TempList = listValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.TempList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.TempList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewItem viewItem = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            viewItem = new ViewItem();

            LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.ContextObj.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, null);

            viewItem.NazwaInwentaryzacji = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.NazwaInwentaryzacji);
            viewItem.DataInwentaryzacji = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.DataInwentaryzacji);
            viewItem.NrInwentaryzacji = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.NrInwentaryzacji);


            convertView.setTag(viewItem);
        }
        else
        {
            viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewItem.NazwaInwentaryzacji.setText(TempList.get(position).NazwaInwentaryzacji);
        viewItem.DataInwentaryzacji.setText('['+TempList.get(position).DataInwentaryzacji+']');
        viewItem.NrInwentaryzacji.setText(TempList.get(position).NrInwentaryzacji+'.');


        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewItem

{
    TextView NazwaInwentaryzacji;
    TextView DataInwentaryzacji;
    TextView NrInwentaryzacji;
    TextView idInwentaryzacji;
    TextView Odswiez;
//    TextView FruitNameTextView;
//    TextView EmailName;

}
```

Comment: You can use one adapter for as many activities as you want. You need to set adapter on every listview whenever you want to use the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make one ListAdapter depend on which Activity is selected to display a specific view?

Yes, you can use the same Adapter for all `Activity`s. Right now, your `ListViewAdapter` Constructor takes a `List` as parameter. If you also pass in the layout resource id which the `LayoutInflater` has to inflate then you can use it in `getView()`.

BTW you are also passing a `Context` into the Constructor. You don't have to do so because in `getView()` you can write

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

Let's assume you have two `Activity`s with layout files like this:

activity1.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity2.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in onCreate() of each `Activity` you can call a method `initListView()`. The following method belongs to Activity1, for Activity2 simply exchange the '1' for a '2':

```
private void initListView()
    {
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List<String> myDatalist = new ArrayList<>();
        ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(myDatalist, R.layout.list_row_1); 
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }
```

You will have noticed that I changed the Adapter's Constructor. My version of ListViewAdapter looks like this:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<FruitNames> TempList;
    private int layoutResId;

    public ListViewAdapter(List<FruitNames> listValue, int layoutResId)
    {
        this.TempList = listValue;
        this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    // other methods like before...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewItem viewItem = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            viewItem = new ViewItem();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResId, null);
            viewItem.NazwaInwentaryzacji = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.NazwaInwentaryzacji);
            viewItem.DataInwentaryzacji = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.DataInwentaryzacji);
            viewItem.NrInwentaryzacji = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.NrInwentaryzacji);
            convertView.setTag(viewItem);
        }
        else{
            viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewItem.NazwaInwentaryzacji.setText(TempList.get(position).NazwaInwentaryzacji);
        viewItem.DataInwentaryzacji.setText('['+TempList.get(position).DataInwentaryzacji+']');
        viewItem.NrInwentaryzacji.setText(TempList.get(position).NrInwentaryzacji+'.');
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner. can you show how to use it?
How do you know which list view to which activity? some If I have to use?

Comment: @laptom - I know which `ListView` id is valid for which `Activity` because each `Activity` has a layout file assigned to it by calling `setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);` in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

**Activity one**

```
 firstListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
 yourAdapter=new PlayerAdapter(FirstActivity.this,dataList);
 firstListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

**Activity two**

```
 secondListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
 yourAdapter=new PlayerAdapter(SecondActivity.this,dataList);
 secondListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

This is how you can use on diffrent activities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the **same object type** (*in your case FruitNames*), and the **way you display that item does not change**, you can **reuse your adapter** in other activities without any problem.

On the other hand, if you're going to use the **same data source**, but want to **display your items in different ways**, you can use the [getItemViewType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) method to use different layouts depending on your position.

Finally, if your **data source changes**, I recommend creating a **new adapter**, this will help you to have your classes **cleaner and easier to read**.